Picking elements of object, free objects
I want to generalize notion of picking elements of object $\mathcal{A}$ by assigning to each element of it some morphism $\mathcal{Z} \to \mathcal{A}$. For example picking element from commutative ring $R$(in category of commutative rings with unital morphisms) is the same to setting up a morphism $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to R$. In $\mathbf{Grp}$ role of this object plays group $\mathbb{Z}$. In category of sets analogue is just singleton.
Is there any generalization which not based on forgetful functor to $\mathbf{Set}$?
P.S. If we take some object $\mathcal{A}$, by this logic we should have epi $\sum_{f \in \mathbf{Hom}(\mathcal{Z},\mathcal{A})} f : \sum_{f \in \mathbf{Hom}(\mathcal{Z},\mathcal{A})} \mathcal{Z} \to \mathcal{A}$.

If you don't have a forgetful functor to sets then what do you mean by "element"?

What you're trying to articulate sounds similar to what's discussed in the following youtube video, which you may find interesting: https://youtu.be/5uI0uJpsEhI?si=RFGbndlxy0F82uoj

You need a representable forgetful functor to the category of sets, otherwise it's unclear what you mean with a (classical) element. If that is represented by an object $F$, then morphisms from $F$ to an object $X$ are corresponding to elements of the underlying set of $X$.
In categories of algebras $F$ is always the free algebra on one generator.
But even though most categories in practice have a forgetful functor to the category of sets, (a) this forgetful functor should not used to understand the category alone since the category can also speak for "itself" without referring to the category of sets, (b) it is only representable in special cases, and even if it is representable the elements we get are perhaps not the ones we are interested in.
Instead, we take a vast generalization and call every morphism from $T$ to $X$ a generalized element of $X$ of shape $T$, regardless of what $T$ is. For more information please check out the nlab and related questions about generalized elements. A quite instructive example I find is that for categories of sheaves, we get all local sections of a sheaf $G$ as generalized elements of $G$ (not just the global sections!).
The epimorphism you mentioned means that $\mathcal{Z}$ is a generator aka separator. See nlab again.
